# Statistics for Isabelle development

Tags: isabelle

I have a lengthy development in Isabelle and I'd like to have some statistics about how many lines are for definitions, how many for statements, and how many are comments.

Is there any such a tool included in Isabelle (such as coqwc for coq)? I've read the *Isabelle System Manual* but couldn't find anything relevant.